# Helm chart identifies numeric string as a number when creating a namespace

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am trying to create a helm deployment where one of the templates is creating a namespace as below

```
apiVersion : v1
kind : Namespace
metadata :
  name : "{{ .Values.productId }}"
```

I am passing the value for the productId in values file as follows:

```
productId: "32345"
```

I get the following error when I do helm install/upgrade

> Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest:
> unable to decode "": json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct
> field ObjectMeta.metadata.namespace of type string helm.go:84: [debug]
> unable to decode "": json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct
> field ObjectMeta.metadata.namespace of type string

I am using helm version 3.8.2. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: try name without quote `name : {{ .Values.productId }}`

Comment: @HarshManvar I have tried without qutoes, with `{{ .Values.productId | toString }}` and by passing productId as `productId: !!str 32345` but all the methods throw the same error.

Comment: working fine for me even without any change, however, i am on version 3.9

Comment: Have you tried `name: {{ .Values.productId | quote }}` (no quotes)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is no issue with the template that you have shared however i hope there is no next line

If you notice the error correctly it's on the `ObjectMeta.metadata.namespace`

Tried with the same version & config working fine for me [image]